# Custom Rules - Disable Constructor Implementation on child Class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oop, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I am writing a Factory Pattern based solution in C#.

Where there is `Abstract class` called `Animal` and any sub class of the `Animal` will be instantiated through a Factory Pattern by passing the Type.

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    protected abstract void Constructor();

    public Animal()
    {
        Constructor();
    }
}   

public class Dog : Animal
{
    protected override void Constructor()
    {
        //Constructor Code here
    }
}
```

I don't wont any of my team mate to misuse the above code by declaring their own public constructor in their child class (eg: cat) and call the constructor directly (eg: `Animal cat = new Cat();`) without using the factory.

How to create a Code Analysis rule that will throw error when compiling such class?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure _why_ you would want to do this. What does it bring you over just using constructors? Maybe you should show us the code for the factory? Oh, and you might also want to read about [CA2214](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182331.aspx) and about [when initializers are executed](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/02/18/why-do-initializers-run-in-the-opposite-order-as-constructors-part-two/).

Answer (score 0):

Couple of options:

You could put the class, its derived classes and the factory into its own assembly & make the classes' constructors internal. If the Factory method is public then anything that references the assembly will only be able to create it via the Factory.

Another option is to make the Factory nested inside the Animal class, something like:

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    protected abstract void Constructor();

    protected Animal()
    {
        Constructor();
    }

    public class Factory
    {
        public static Animal CreateAnimal()
        {
            return new Animal();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The classes themselves should be public, only their constructors should be internal.

Answer (score -1):

if you will add any `parameter` or `dummy parameter` to `base class` then it will not offer `default constructor` in `child classes.`

Example:

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    protected abstract void Constructor();

    public Animal(bool DoNotAllowDefaultConstructor)
    {
        Constructor();
    }
}
```

**In this way  the derived class must make an explicit call to a base class constructor by using the base keyword**

```
public class Dog : Animal
{
    protected override void Constructor()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("I'm a dog");
    }

    public Dog():base(false)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("I'm a dog's default constructor");
    }
}
```

Look [here](http://dotnet4u-me.blogspot.com.tr/2010/05/c-interview-questions-on-constructors.html) for more detailed information

Comment: Now you can directly call Animal myAnimal = new Dog(); // Which is wrong,  it is skipping the Factory Pattern